# Check the value of an option in a unit test for Picocli

Tags: java, unit-testing, picocli

In a unit test for a utility using [picocli](https://picocli.info/), I would like to assert that picocli assigned the correct value to the option. How can I get the value associated with an option in a unit test?

Here is the current version of the unit test:

```java
@Test
void callWithOptionForSuffix() {
    NextMajorSubcommand command = new NextMajorSubcommand();
    CommandLine cmdline = new CommandLine(command);

    ParseResult parseResult = cmdline.parseArgs("--suffix", "DELTA", "4.5.6");

    assertThat(parseResult.hasMatchedPositional(0)).isTrue();
    assertThat(parseResult.matchedOptions()).isNotEmpty();
    assertThat(parseResult.matchedOption("--suffix").isOption());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Picocli offers the method `getValue()` to get the parsed value for an option.

```java
assertThat(parseResult.matchedOption("--suffix").String>getValue())
    .hasValue("DELTA");
```